# Application Insight Performance Counter in Azure

Tags: performance, azure, cloud, performancecounter, azure-application-insights

Application Insight is monitoring default Performance counters when I am running my web application from my local system. But problem is its not showing any data when it is deployed in Azure . Do you have any idea regarding this? 
Below are the parts of my ApplicationInsight.config

```
<TelemetryModules>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector" />
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector"></Add>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.Tracing.DiagnosticsTelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" />
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.DeveloperModeWithDebuggerAttachedTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.RequestTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ExceptionTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
```

```
<TelemetryChannel Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel" />
<TelemetryInitializers>
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.DomainNameRoleInstanceTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.BuildInfoConfigComponentVersionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.DeviceTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.SyntheticTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.UserAgentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationNameTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.UserTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.SessionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
```

e109768a-9c9a-4f23-96d4-47c65c2e7d58

Comment: You will need to provide more information in order for people to help you. What steps did you follow to configure Application Insights?

Comment: Thanks.. I have edited the question ..

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about Azure WebApp then performance counters collection is currently not exposed there and there's work happening now to make it available. For my regret I cannot provide any concrete ETA for this to be done but hope that it'll be available soon.